# Loop for BigInteger numbers java

Tags: java, for-loop, biginteger

I'm using the code down below to find **perfect square** numbers but can't do the large numbers like `BigInteger`s and another problem is that I can't create a perfect loop

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int q = in.nextInt();
        BigInteger[] l = new BigInteger[q];
        BigInteger[] r = new BigInteger[q];
        int[] num = new int[q];
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            l[i] = in.nextBigInteger();
            r[i] = in.nextBigInteger();
            num[i]=0;
            for (BigInteger j = l[i]; j.compareTo(r[i]) > 0; j.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
                **This loop doesn't work**
            }            
        }
```

Comment: Can you share some sample input and the expected output for it?

Comment: yes l = 3 and r = 9 , between 3 and 9 there are two perfect square {4.9} and It should count two(2)

Comment: Actually I did it with little number like the example but I expect it to work with bigintegers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, Assuming that `j` starts out as smallers than `r[i]`, you have the condition reversed - as long as it's smaller, `j.compareTo(r[i]` will return a value that's less than zero, not greater than zero. Second, `add` does not modify a `BigInteger` instance, it returns a new `BigInteger` with the result of the addition (i.e., you can think as it as being the `+` operator, not the `+=` operator).

In short, this is what your loop should look like:

```java
for (BigInteger j = l[i]; j.compareTo(r[i]) < 0; j = j.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    // Code goes here...
```